# OOP Laravel - How do I handle Common Functions over Multiple Controllers?

Tags: php, oop, laravel

Say I have several controllers.  One for foods, one for cars, one for electronics. Each of these handles image uploads from a form, moving the files into the proper subfolders.

Currently I have the function to move the files in EACH of the controllers, which is not efficient. What is the proper strategy to put the function in a controller of its own and utilize it from multiple controllers.

Update for Clarification

So I want a controller with a function named StoreImage and would like to call it as StoreImage(arguments)

Comment: A trait - or extend from a common class.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Job Bus (Previously Command Bus in 5.0). http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#writing-job-classes

For uploads I would suggest using a self-handling job as that will remove a layer of complexity for handing an upload.

This allows you to create a common piece of functionality that can be triggered anywhere in the application.